# Application runtime path "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ads/protected/runtime" is not valid. in linux

Tags: reactjs

While I am running the page I get the below issue:

> "Application runtime path "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ads/protected/runtime" is
>   not valid."

How can I fix this in the OS?

Comment: Could you please mention your version of Linux, also some more information about what you have already tried and installed might be useful.

Comment: linux mint and  i had  tried to change the grub.conf and selinux file but i cant

Comment: Please add that information to you question and also specify the error you are getting, or why you are unable to do so.